# Sometime, object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I try to solve this problem but I can't.
It has a problem about iteration.

views.py

```
if borrow:
    borrow_item = Borrow_Item.objects.filter(borrow_id = borrow)
    for it in items:
        it_id = int(it)
        item_id = Item.objects.get(id=it_id)
        count = 0
        for brit in borrow_item:
            if item_id.id == brit.item_id.id:
                count = count+1
                break
        if count == 0:
            borrow_item = Borrow_Item(id=None, borrow_id=borrow, item_id=item_id)
            borrow_item.save()
```

Sometime, it shows " 'Borrow_Item' object is not iterable ".
These are case that it's normal.

- Choose one new item.
- Choose more than one, by all items that select has been selected previously.(item is in cart)
- Choose two item, by choose one item has been selected and that item id less than another item id (new item).

In the case that it causes an error.

- Choose more than one, by there are at least one item that has id less than existing items id

Sorry, If I can't communicate to you to understand

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because of the following line:

```py
borrow_item = Borrow_Item.objects.filter(borrow_id = borrow)
```

You gave to the result of your query the same name of the item you create at the very end, so after the first item creation your queryset becomes a `Borrow_Item` object, which is not iterable.

Rename it to something else, `borrow_items` for instance, and it should work:

```py
if borrow:
    borrow_items = Borrow_Item.objects.filter(borrow_id = borrow)
    for it in items:
        it_id = int(it)
        item_id = Item.objects.get(id=it_id)
        count = 0
        for brit in borrow_items:
            if item_id.id == brit.item_id.id:
                count = count+1
                break
        if count == 0:
            borrow_item = Borrow_Item(id=None, borrow_id=borrow, item_id=item_id)
            borrow_item.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

borrow_item = Borrow_Item.objects.filter(borrow_id = borrow) applies a filter, which will filter out whatever Borrow_Items that don't have that borrow_id. It seems that your third use case causes that to be empty/ or None, and an alike object is not iterable.

you can solve this by:

```
borrow_item =  Borrow_Item.objects.filter(borrow_id = borrow)
if not borrow_item: 
  print("no items borrowed") 
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem! I move `borrow_item = Borrow_Item.objects.filter(borrow_id = borrow)` into loop as follows.

```
if borrow:
    for it in items:
        it_id = int(it)
        item_id = Item.objects.get(id=it_id)
        count = 0
        borrow_item = Borrow_Item.objects.filter(borrow_id = borrow)
        for brit in borrow_item:
            if item_id.id == brit.item_id.id:
                count = count+1
                break
        if count == 0:
            borrow_item = Borrow_Item(id=None, borrow_id=borrow, item_id=item_id)
            borrow_item.save()
```